# How to create a 8bit array where the array can only store 0 and 1 in java

Tags: java, arrays

How to convert the
number(random integer within 0 – 255) to binary and store the bit into an 8 bit array.(java)

Comment: Please take the [tour] first. Also read [ask] either. After these actions, come back and ask your questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "8bit array"?

Comment: how about `byte b = (byte)input;` ?? (A byte is (accidentally/fortunately) a 8-bit-array;) ..to "unwrap it unsigned" again (0...255): `System.out.println(b & 0xFF);`

Comment: to get something like `b[3]`, you can: `(b >> (3-1)) & 1;`

Comment: ... there is no `bit` (type) in java ... and in (current/"modern") computer architecture the smallest "addressable" memory unit is byte... But BitSet is a *very nice & useful* class (backed by a `long[]`)

Answer (score 4):

You may look at [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class, which *implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are indexed by nonnegative integers. Individual indexed bits can be examined*:

```java
BitSet myByte = new BitSet(8);
```

To convert the `byte` value to the `BitSet`, there are methods [`BitSet.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf-byte:A-) and [`BitSet::toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray--):

```java
byte b = 111;
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{b});

byte fromBits = bits.toByteArray()[0];
```

Comment: Your code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`.  `new byte[b]` → `new byte[] {b}`?

Comment: @sadetaosa, right, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bit Masking` to convert an int to binary.

```java
public static int[] getBits(int number) {
    assert (0 <= number && number <= 255);
    int[] bits = new int[8];
    for (int i = 7; i >=0; i--) {
        int mask = 1 << i;
        bits[7-i] = (number & mask) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return bits;
}
```